# Postgresql Trying to calculate percentage of total using over(). Never used over() before but I've read this is the proper approach

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Here is my simple table structure with a couple results:
[image]

The ages range from 18 - 100

I'm try to calculate the percentage of an age range that has a good job, such as 18 - 24, 24-30 etc. I need to sum the 'good_jobs' because this is survey data, and many did not respond, so many null values.

I'm trying combine what I can do in multiple queries into a single one:

query1:

```
select sum(good_job) as "18_24_GoodJobs"
from jf_q2
where
age >= 18 and age <= 24
and
working=1;
```

result 61

query2:

```
select sum(good_job) as "18_24_GoodJobs"
from jf_q2
where
age >= 18 and age <= 100
and
working=1;
```

result 2571

with a single query doing something like this:

```
select sum(good_job) as "18to24",
(sum(good_job)/ (select sum(good_job over(partition by good_job))) as Percentage)
from jf_q2
where
age >= 18 and age <= 24
and
working=1;
```

result = some_fractional number

I'm hoping for something like

```
18_24_GoodJobs| all_with_good_jobs
61 | 16%
```

Ultimately this is a flask app and I'll have to deal with this later, but I'm trying to get this query down to draw a graphic.

Thank you and Happy Sunday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(good_job) filter(where age between 18 and 24) 18_24_GoodJobs,
    sum(good_job) filter(where age between 18 and 24)
        / sum(good_job) 18_24_GoodJobs_Part
from jf_q2
where working = 1
```

This gives you the count of good jobs for age 18-24 and the proportion of age 18-24 amongst good jobs (as a decimal value).

Comment: W00T! That worked! I had to add parenthesis around the aliases, but you've saved me!